# Adding Color to textAngular is there an easy way to cause the colorpicker to close on click within the textAngular editor?

Tags: angularjs, user-interface

A fair number have asked about adding font and background color to textAngular.  I am fairly happy with my solution, so I thought I would share this.  I do have one last question: is there an easy way to have the colorpicker close when the editor is clicked? without modifying the textAngular code which I wanted to avoid?

In this solution I am using the angular-bootstrap-colorpicker, so I have also added as a dependency to my app:   [ ... 'colorpicker.module', 'textAngular', ... ].

Following https://github.com/fraywing/textAngular/wiki/Customising-The-Toolbar I have in the config section of my app:

```
    $provide.decorator('taOptions', ['taRegisterTool', '$delegate', function(taRegisterTool, taOptions){
      // $delegate is the taOptions we are decorating
      // register the tool with textAngular

      taRegisterTool('backgroundColor', {
        display: "<button colorpicker class='btn btn-default ng-scope' title='Background Color' type='button' colorpicker-close-on-select colorpicker-position='bottom' ng-model='backgroundColor' style='background-color: {{backgroundColor}}'><i class='fa fa-paint-brush'></i></button>",
        action: function (deferred) {
          var self = this;
          this.$editor().wrapSelection('backgroundColor', this.backgroundColor);
          if (typeof self.listener == 'undefined') {
            self.listener = self.$watch('backgroundColor', function (newValue) {
              self.$editor().wrapSelection('backColor', newValue);
            });
          }
          self.$on('colorpicker-selected', function () {
            deferred.resolve();
          });
          self.$on('colorpicker-closed', function () {
            deferred.resolve();
          });
          return;
        }
      });
      taOptions.toolbar[1].unshift('backgroundColor');

      taRegisterTool('fontColor', {
        display: "<button colorpicker type='button' class='btn btn-default ng-scope'  title='Font Color'  colorpicker-close-on-select colorpicker-position='bottom' ng-model='fontColor' style='color: {{fontColor}}'><i class='fa fa-font '></i></button>",
        action: function (deferred) {
          var self = this;
          if (typeof self.listener == 'undefined') {
            self.listener = self.$watch('fontColor', function (newValue) {
              self.$editor().wrapSelection('foreColor', newValue);
            });
          }
          self.$on('colorpicker-selected', function () {
            deferred.resolve();
          });
          self.$on('colorpicker-closed', function () {
            deferred.resolve();
          });
          return false;
        }
      });
      taOptions.toolbar[1].unshift('fontColor');

      taOptions.setup.textEditorSetup=function($element) {
        $element.attr('ui-codemirror', '');
      };
      return taOptions;
    }]);

  })
```

where the 'ui-codemirror' is not related to the addition of color to textAngular, just part of my code.

I hope this is helpful to others, as I mentioned above, I only wish that I could cause the colorpicker to close when I click away onto the editor...

Here is a picture of the resultant addition to the UI.

[image: picture of the toolbar with the added color for font and background]

Comment: If you have solved your problem. Then please do separate port for it. Problems should go on question and answer it on answer section. This way it will help other user to find out your problem and solutions.

Comment: Your question lists under the unsolved questions. Please move the solution to an answer and accept yourself.